# Eloquent laravel : Get JSON representation of entry in table with all his relations

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Model **Ov.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ov extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'ov';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = array('version', 'macAddress');
    protected $hidden = array('timestamps');

    public function masters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MasterEquipment', 'id_ov_foreign_key');
    }

}
```

Model **MasterEquipment.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MasterEquipment extends Model 
{

    protected $table = 'masterEquipment';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = array('macAddress');

    public function slaveEquipments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SlaveEquipment', 'id_masterEquipment_foreign_key');
    }

    public function equipment()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Equipment', 'id_masterEquipment_foreign_key');
    }

}
```

I would like to retrieve the entire JSON representation for a given version of OV:
I tried :

```
return Ov::where('version', '3')->with('masters')->get();
```

But it doesn't work, I only get the following JSON: (with masters empty)

```
{
   "version": 3,
   "macAddress": "00:01:02:04:04",
   "masters":[]
}
```

Could you help me please ?

Comment: See this [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json), its help full

Comment: Please add your database scheme for `Ov` and `MasterEquipment` to your question. The opposite of `hasmany()` should be `belongsTo()` not `hasOne()`

Comment: What are the primary key column names of both of these tables?

Comment: @Björn Is-it mandatory to add the belongsTo() relation in the other model when i create an hasMany relation ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos: No it's not. You should add your table schemas to the question post for people to solve the bug you are having.

Comment: What happens if you change: return Ov::where('version', '3')->with('masters')->get(); to return Ov::with('masters')->where('version', '3')->get();?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) for that.

It's pretty simple.  Instead of returning your model you will return your resource and pass your model into the resource collection as follows:

```
return new OvCollection(Ov::where('version', '3')->with('masters')->get());
```

You have to create your resource collection first of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation builder is wrong.
From your model i conclude that your two tables are like this

**ov table**

```
------------------------------
id   |  version  | macAddress
------------------------------
```

**masterEquipment table**

```
---------------------
id   |  macAddress
---------------------
```

Only thing that is relating both table is `macAddress`

So your modal relation should be like this

**Ov modal**

```
 public function masters()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MasterEquipment:class, 'macAddress','macAddress);
    }
```

Then only this will work

```
return Ov::where('version', '3')->with('masters')->get();
```